# Zabbix performance study

Tags: zabbix

I am doing some studies of performance for Zabbix and i am searching some information for having a relation between created values per second (information that Zabbix give to us nowadays) and consumed CPU resources (and maybe physical memory).

Right now, i know that the main CPU eating element in Zabbix is the growing of our Database, is here mentioned : https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/1.8/manual/installation/requirements

But i need more specifics calculus for knowing the evolution of the CPU spending in relation with the created valors per second (no a "rule of 3"...).

Anyone has any idea or document where i can find this information??

I need all this for future "resource planning", because i will add new elements in the future, and i need planning when my resources will be insufficient in terms of CPU and RAM memory.

The number of users connected to the front-web is constant.

Thank you very much all.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to monitor Zabbix performance is through [internal items](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.2/manual/config/items/itemtypes/internal).

For instance, item `zabbix[requiredperformance]` will show you the same theoretical "New values per second" value as the frontend does, but item `zabbix[wcache,<cache>,<mode>]` will show you how many values per second are actually gathered and split them by type.

Other item particularly useful for performance monitoring is `zabbix[process,<type>,<mode>,<state>]` which will show exactly how busy Zabbix processes are.

Most of these items are available in "Template App Zabbix Server", which comes by default with Zabbix 2.2.